# systemctl --user returns "Unit was not found" on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, services, systemd, 18.04

I just fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04. I am having an issue with systemd, which worked fine with 17.10. My service files are located in `~/.config/systemd/user`.

I tried a `daemon-reload`. didn't work. I keep getting an error saying

```
failed to start. Unit was not found.
```

Comment: Could your HOME directory be on a different partition than /etc, or might you have HOME directory encryption? Systemd might not be able to resolve the /etc/systemd/system/* soft links properly in these cases, thus does not find them on boot.